# A matrix with at least one (real) non-zero eigenvalue

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Suppose $A$ is an $n\times n$ matrix over the set of non-negative integers. Is there a necessary condition for $A$ so that it would have at least one real non-zero eigenvalue?

Ignore what's written below:

I'm just wondering, given an $n\times n$ matrix $A$ over the set of non-negative integers, is there a necessary condition for $A$ to have at least one real, non-zero eigenvalue?

Edit: If we know that $A$ doesn't have a row that is completely zero, would this suffice?

Comment: $A$ has at least one real, non-zero eigenvalue iff its characteristic polynomial has at least one real, non-zero root.

Comment: @RobArthan sure, but what if the entries of $A$ are unknown? So I was hoping for something that only relies on a particular property of $A$ (if there is such...)

Comment: You ask first for a necessary condition. Then the edit suggests a possible sufficient condition. Which are you looking for?

Comment: @RGB Hmm, good point. let me edit it again. I think I've made up my mind on what my question would be like.

Comment: What do you mean by a "particular property"? The conjecture you added in your edit is wrong - rotations in the plane have no non-zero eigenvalues, but are non-singular.

Comment: @RobArthan - I meant, given a matrix with no zero row, then does it mean that the matrix has at least one non-zero real eigenvalue?

This is that "particular property" I'm trying to hit, whether a row of zeros, or upper triangular matrix, etc.

Comment: BTW, thanks for all your response, and this is not a homework or anything. Just a product of a curious mind. =)

Answer (score 2):

By the [Perron-Frobenius theorem and its extension to the nonnegative matrices](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perron%E2%80%93Frobenius_theorem#Non-negative_matrices), a matrix with nonnegative elements either has only zeroes as the eigenvalues or it has to have at least one real non-zero eigenvalue, because it has one that is - in absolute value - greater than or equal to all the others (so it cannot be zero).